# How to get nowrap in Spannable in TextView?

Tags: android, textview, spannable, nowrap

Is it possible to make only a part of the text in TextView not wrap to the next line?

Currently I have:

```
|Some long description [kg/|
|m^2]                      |
```

On small screens I want:

```
|Some long description     |
|[kg/m^2]                  |
```

But if there is enough space on the screen I want:

```
|Some long description [kg/m^2]         |
```

so that the part of the text `[kg/m^2]` is always in one piece.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create separate layouts for the different screen sizes using smallest width qualifier.
2. Separate the description and the units in separate TextViews.
3. For smaller screens place the TextViews in a LinearLayout with orientation set to vertical.
4. For larger screens place the TextViews in a LinearLayout with orientation set to horizontal.

See here for more details
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html